# Realm does not seem to persist data between session or app upgrade

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, realm, realm-mobile-platform

In the `AppDelegate.swift` file, in the function `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {`

```
do {
        let fileURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("main-tocca.realm")
        let realmConfig = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: fileURL, readOnly: false, schemaVersion: 4, migrationBlock: { (migration, oldSchemaVersion) in
            NSLog("\(#function) | Migration")
            if oldSchemaVersion < 4 {
                NSLog("\(#function) | Migration to version 4")
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Source.className()) { (_, newSource) in
                    newSource?["fileName"] = ""
                }
            }
        }, deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true, shouldCompactOnLaunch: { (totalBytes, usedBytes) -> Bool in
            // totalBytes refers to the size of the file on disk in bytes (data + free space)
            // usedBytes refers to the number of bytes used by data in the file

            // Compact if the file is over 100MB in size and less than 50% 'used'
            let oneHundredMB = 100 * 1024 * 1024
            return (totalBytes > oneHundredMB) && (Double(usedBytes) / Double(totalBytes)) < 0.5
        })

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = realmConfig

        autoreleasepool {
            do {
                // Realm is compacted on the first open if the configuration block conditions were met.
                _ = try Realm(configuration: realmConfig)
            } catch {
                NSLog("\(#function) | Realm Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                SentryEventReportManager.report(err: error)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        NSLog("\(#function) | Realm File Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        SentryEventReportManager.report(err: error)
    }
}
```

One of the very first operation the app is performing just after starting is to access a local database and look for the presence of certains objects that should have been persisted during the previous usage of the app.

Using the RealmStudio I can see that the database is persisted properly, but when using on a real device I noticed based on the app behavior that the database may not be properly persisted so no error is returned when writing or reading the database (all the `throws` are properly caught)

Some people have reported a similar issue, and the answer was to rename the `default.realm` file (what I'm doing) but it seems to be still occurring.